# Track contacts who attended more than 1 event

Tags: contacts, reports

Is there a way to track contacts that have registered for more than 1 event within the past 12 months?
Either through reports or smart groups or any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily GROUP BY and COUNT() in mysql - do you have access to mysql? If not you can also put this in to a CiviCRM custom report.

Here's the query:

So below contact_id 2309 participated in 5 events; contact_id 3186 in 2 etc.

```
    mysql> SELECT contact_id, COUNT(*) from civicrm_participant GROUP BY contact_id HAVING COUNT(*)>1
+------------+----------+
| contact_id | COUNT(*) |
+------------+----------+
|       2309 |        5 |
|       3186 |        2 |
|       3568 |        2 |
|       5820 |        2 |
|       7007 |        3 |
|       7045 |        3 |
|       7048 |        3 |
|       7083 |        3 |
```

Comment: Where do I go to create a custom report in Civicrm. Only options I see are existing reports...

Comment: You'll have to add code. Then register your report. This is still a very good how-to reference: https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/civicrm-creating-a-custom-report/

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal you can build Views with Aggregation, which could provide you a list of names and 'count' of events they have attended. Not certain about ability to filter or sort on that value though.